# Allow all users access to virtual computer. VMPLAYER + Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware, virtual-machine

Installed VmPlayer on a PC that runs Windows 7.
I logged as admin and installed Ubuntu Linux via VmPlayer.
When I log in as 'user', VmPlayer does not show the Ubuntu installation.

Is there a way to allow all users on that PC, to access that Ubuntu virtual PC?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

When you create / install your virtual machine as admin, you probably saved it in the default Window location: `C:\Users\admin\Documents\Virtual Machines\`

And after with the user, VM-Player displays only the VM in that location: `C:\Users\user\Documents\Virtual Machines\`

Personally I save all my VM's on a separate (external) hard disk. But you can also save it in a public folder on the `C` Drive which will be common for both users (eg. `C:\Users\Public\Virtual Machines`).

Another possible solution: executing `vmplayer` process with administrative rights (shift-right click, then `Run as Administrator`).